# How to resolve the watershed delineation failure in QGIS due to NO DATA values in 'Flow Direction File'?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga, watershed, catchment

How can I resolve the issue of getting errors while delineating a watershed in QGIS? I have tried using different DEMs (ALOS and Cartosat), but I am consistently encountering NO DATA values in the FLOW DIRECTION file, which is preventing successful delineation. Interestingly, when using the same DEM in ArcGIS and HEC-HMS, there are no NO DATA values in the FLOW DIRECTION file and the watershed is correctly delineated.

I have attached a [**Zip file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZOafsz2ELm10yw-9vjsumGHiXXwN0k6/view?usp=sharing) containing the *ALOS DEM* for inspection. Can anyone offer insight into why NO DATA values are appearing in the FLOW DIRECTION file in QGIS?

**Below is the screenshot of problem with the process in QGIS:**
[image: Issues with channel delineation in QGIS]

**However, as I said I could delineate it in ArcGIS. The delineated watershed and streams for ArcGIS are shown for the area where QGIS is failing.**
[image: Delineated watershed in ArcGIS]

**Just to add another tool, here is the delineated catchment in HEC-HMS:**
[image: Delineated watershed in ArcGIS]

**To me it seems, due to flat topography QGIS is failing to generate the Flow Direction properly, as shown below.**
[image: Flow Direction in QGIS]

How to resolve this error in QGIS.

Comment: Which algorithm are you using in QGIS? GRASS GIS tools such as r.watershed?

Comment: I tried r.watershed in Grass as well as Terrain Analysis in SAGA. Problem is with the incorrect flow direction file generation which has NO DATA values. I have attached the DEM, you may like to give it a shot.

Comment: I realized the SAGA dails to delineate the catchment, though it could be done in GRASS.

Answer (score 2):

The GRASS r.watershed has a few settings that may help. Check the "Enable Single Flow Direction" and the "Beautify flat areas":
[image]

I ran r.watershed with your DEM and these settings, and got these stream segments:
[image]

I'm not familiar with this specific area of the world so don't know if the stream segments are necessarily correct, but overall looks ok to me. Flat areas are indeed problematic.

BTW, the stream segments in my screen shot are the raster stream segments produced by r.watershed, after conversion to vector (using r.to.vect) for visualization purposes (the pixelated stream segments were too thin).